# Python Mock: mock calls counted by call_count

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

Is there a way to get the mock calls counted by `call_count` in this example:

```
from mock import MagicMock

mock = MagicMock()
mock.get_query(arg=1).execute()
mock.get_query(arg=2).execute()

print('count:', mock.get_query.call_count)
print('calls:', mock.get_query.mock_calls)
```

Actual result:

```
count: 2
calls: [call(arg=1), call().execute(), call(arg=2), call().execute()]
```

Desired result:

```
count: 2
calls: [call(arg=1), call(arg=2)]
```

I understand `mock_calls`. The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) is quite clear:

> mock_calls records *all* calls to the mock object, its methods, magic
> methods and return value mocks.

I'm wondering if there's an elegent way to filter `mock_calls`. There's also `method_calls` but it's still not it.

Comment: Does `mock.get_query.call_args_list` give you what you want?

Comment: Yes it does. What a confusing name though... Thank you so much. Please make this as an answer. Although I'm not sure if I should keep this question, I believe other people might not find this obvious as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a list of `call()` objects corresponding to each call made to `mock.get_query`. I think that `mock.get_query.call_args_list` will give you what you want:

```
>>> from mock import MagicMock
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> mock.get_query(arg=1).execute()
<MagicMock name='mock.get_query().execute()' id='139688065592160'>
>>> mock.get_query(arg=2).execute()
<MagicMock name='mock.get_query().execute()' id='139688065592160'>
>>> mock.get_query.call_args_list
[call(arg=1), call(arg=2)]
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.call_args_list):

> `call_args_list`
>
> This is a list of all the calls made to the mock object in sequence (so the length of the list is the number of times it has been called). Before any calls have been made it is an empty list. The call object can be used for conveniently constructing lists of calls to compare with call_args_list.